# Projection mongodb not work - operator $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an array:

```
let arr=["v1","v2","v3"];
```

This array is condition for my query in mongodb. The query in nodejs is:

`cursor = await myCollection.find({"attribute":{ $in: arr}},{_id:0,title:1});`

The result doesn't have the  fields are in the projection. But when I change $in and use $all,the query brings the title field.

Help me please

Comment: I tried similar queries with $in and $all both and project works with both of the queries. which MongoDb version you are using ?

Comment: You are right, it works in the mongoshell. But the code is in nodejs.That is so weird.

Comment: Queries works in nodeJs code as well. Could you please share your NodeJs code.

Comment: @Jitendra my mongo shell is version 4, but I use a lib mongodb for node. It may be.

Comment: @Jitendra The mongodb version in node is 3.1.6

`static async getMoviesByCountry(countries) {
  

      let cursor
      try {
      cursor = await movies.find({"countries":{ $in:countries}},{"_id":0,"title":1});
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`)
        return []
      }
          
      return cursor.toArray()
    }`

Comment: Are you using mongoose (library) or anything else?

Comment: No, But I reviewed the code received, and the id is included when they show the registers. However, It brings all fields yet.

Comment: @Jitendra I found the solution. Look at this http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#find. The library for node has an option called projection. The right code is:   `cursor = await movies.find({"countries": {$in: arr}}, {projection:{_id: 1,title: 1}});`      
Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a very simple words:

**Difference: 1**

`{ $in: ["v1","v2","v3"] }`  works as OR condition and `{ $all: ["v1","v2","v3"] }` 
 works as AND conditions.

With $in if any of value from v1 , v2 and v3 match with "attribute" value then your will get document in result.

With $all if all value from v1, v2, and v3 must exist at "attribute" value then only you will get result document.

**Difference: 2**

$all should be used only on array attribute as if you will use $all on string attribute with two or more value in array then will always get empty result  .

$in can be useful with both type of attributes "array" and "String" as in case of String attribute if any of the value matched with value from array then you will get respective document in result.

Answer (score 1):

In $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array, according to mongoDB documentation.

In $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements, according to mongoDB documentation.

In your case if you use $all instead of using $in, this query check all the elements in your array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But my explanation was not very good. I want this: 
"In $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array, according to mongoDB documentation."

My real problem is the projection, It is not working with $in operator, It brings all fields and I just need one.

Comment: Did you tried just .find() method without $in, it might be work.