# mongo $in on multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get data with `$in` operator on multiple cases,
here below is my sample data

```
[{
    "userId":1,
  "attemptNum":2,
  "submissionCount":1,
  "questionId":1
},
{
    "userId":1,
  "attemptNum":2,
  "submissionCount":2,
  "questionId":1
},
{
    "userId":1,
  "attemptNum":2,
  "submissionCount":1,
  "questionId":2
}]
```

and here below is my query

```
let history = await this.dbCollection.
    .find({
      $and: [
        { userId: 1 },
        { attemptNum: 2 },
        { questionId: { $in: [1, 2] } },
        { submissionCount: { $in: [2, 1] } },
      ],
    })
    .lean();
```

expected output:

```
[{
    "userId":1,
  "attemptNum":2,
  "submissionCount":2,
  "questionId":1
},
{
    "userId":1,
  "attemptNum":2,
  "submissionCount":1,
  "questionId":2
}]
```

One thing i got to know that `$in` works as `$or` by this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286859/projection-mongodb-not-work-operator-in),

for temporary solution i written map and getting the desired output

here below is sample code of map

```
codingHistory.map((mongoHistory) =>{
    submittedQuestionIds.map((postgresData) =>{
      if(postgresData.submissionCount == mongoHistory.submissionCount && postgresData.questionId == mongoHistory.questionId){
        filteredData.push(mongoHistory) 
      }
    })
  })
```

so my question is how can I make this work with a mongo query without external loops

any help or suggestions are really so helpful.

Comment: the query seems ok and the first record passes the filter because both `submissionCount` and `questionId`  values are inside `$in array`. can you elaborate more on how are you trying to filter your data?

Comment: I'm not confident I fully understand the query you want, but is this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GuRJ3Ir2Bnq) what you are looking for?

Comment: ... or perhaps awkwardly, [another mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1M1G4m4J22O)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs thanks for the comment, I made added one more object to the link you shared, and it started to misbehave, please check this playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/UzKE1A_pJVg

Comment: Order matters.  Did you want to try https://mongoplayground.net/p/xOL502XeWAA
?

Comment: thanks, @rickhg12hs, I got this working, `Order matters` this helped to get it done